# Listview lags; issue with cache file?

Tags: android, caching, opengl-es

I have experienced quite a bit of lag recently when using `ListView` in one of my applications. About the same time the problem manifested itself, I started getting the following error message upon shutting down the application.

```
E/libEGL(8501): error creating cache file /data/data/[my application's namespace]/cache/com.android.opengl.shaders_cache: No such file or directory (2)
```

As my device is not rooted, I do not have access to the location and could verify the file exists, is corrupt, or has been deleted. I am not sure what the problem is. First of all, could the problems be related? It seems like a strange coincidence. To be clear; I do use a view holder pattern to optimise my `ListView` and it has worked just fine before so my implementation is an unlikely culprit.

**Update** As requested, here the code for my Adapter's `getView` method. While I don't believe it has anything to do with the problem, it worked fine before for about 5 months just fine, I am happy to cater to your questions.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentViewGroup)
{       
    final PersonaViewHolder viewHolder;
    final Persona persona = provider[position];

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parentViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_personas, null);

        viewHolder = new PersonaViewHolder(
                (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.persona_icon),
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.persona_description));
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (PersonaViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(), persona.getPicture());
    viewHolder.setIcon(icon, 50, 50);
    viewHolder.setDescription(persona.getName() + " is a " + persona.getType() + "!");

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can you post your Adapter `getView()` method?

Answer (score 2):

As your probably are aware, having any type of actual processing in your `getView()` method should be avoided. While I can't speak to the cache file issue, I do notice you have the line:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getResources(), persona.getPicture());
```

In your `getView()` method. You should consider implementing a `LruCache` to cache your bitmaps. Documentation on that can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Additionally, on the line

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parentViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_personas, null);
```

You should not use `.inflate(R.layout.list_personas, null);` but instead use `.inflate(R.layout.list_personas, parent, false);`

Note the difference in the last arguments. This is the proper way to attach your view to it's parent. It may not improve performance, but it's correct.

Comment: Using the alternate signature for `inflate` taking as parameters a `Resource`, a `ViewGroup`, and a `boolean` only results in an error, i.e. `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView`. Hence, I don't use that constructor because it is not correct. If it were correct, it wouldn't result in an exception being thrown. As for your first suggestion, caching was previously being done automatically for my list of four items I suppose as it is what the error I get hints at. As this is gone I really might have to do it manually.

Comment: Check out this article: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: Thank you for the link, very informative. However, trying to use any of the recommended ways to "correct" my code only leads to exceptions.

Comment: I implemented the cache for a larger `ListView` and the problem persists! The `ListView` lags. While your answer has been quite informative, it, unfortunately, fails to solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm, sorry to hear that. Nothing else in your code looks wrong. The only other change I would make is in the `Array` or `Base` Adapter cache the `LayoutInflator` so you don't need to call `LayoutInflater.from(parentViewGroup.getContext())` everytime. Sorry I couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: No worries, you gave me a few good pointers. The lack of documentation of this problem on the internet as well as it likely not being due (or at least not completely) to my code makes it hard to solve. I appreciate your willingness to help!